# How to fix GDB's error "Invalid address specified to RtlFreeHeap"

Tags: c, gdb

I have some troubles working on a piece of C code.
Here is my code:

```c
typedef struct ARRAY {
    int length;
    int* values;
} ARRAY;


ARRAY* ARRAY_init(int length) {
    ARRAY* a = malloc(sizeof(ARRAY));
    a->values = malloc(length * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        a->values[i] = 0;
    }
    a->length = length;
    return a;
}


void ARRAY_free(ARRAY* a) {
    free(a->values);
    free(a);
}


void ARRAY_extend(ARRAY* a, int k) {
    a->values = realloc(a->values, a->length + k);
    for (int i = a->length; i < a->length + k; i++) {
        a->values[i] = 0;
    }
    a->length += k;
}


int main() {
    ARRAY* a = ARRAY_init(3);
    ARRAY_extend(a, 2);
    ARRAY_free(a);
}
```

When i run this piece of code with gdb, i get a
`warning: Heap block at 00AD16B8 modified at 00AD16CC past requested size of 5`
and then a
`warning: Invalid address specified to RtlFreeHeap( 00AD0000, 00AD16C0 )`
The error seems to occure during the `realloc`...
Still I don't understand what is wrong with my code. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: It is not GDB's error. Do you get it when running this code without gdb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`realloc` takes input as number of bytes to be allocated.

```
   a->values = realloc(a->values, a->length + k);
```

should be

```
   a->values = realloc(a->values, sizeof(int) * (a->length + k));
```

As of now you are just allocating `5` bytes but you meant `5 * sizeof(int)` bytes.

---

Or even better is

```
    int *temp = realloc(a->values, sizeof(int) * (a->length + k));
    if (temp) {
       a->values = temp;
       a->length += k;
    }
    else {
       //error
    }
```